# SQL - Select invalid column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I ran into a little error trying to select off of my table. I am sure it is an easy fix but I can't seem to locate the problem. It seems that my error message is telling me that I am selecting off a column that does not exist, even though it does.

**The code**

```
SELECT TOP (20) id 
FROM school b 
WHERE b.state = school.state 
AND b.id <> school.id 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

**The table "school"**

[image: School table]

**The error msg**

[image: Error msg]

Comment: you'll need to provide some more context information regarding this: how is the query run? what is it supposed to do? My hunch is that you need to have two parameters in the query, but we need to see how the query is formed in order to advise how to add them.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear before. Luckily someone was able to pick out what I needed. Problem solved ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve with this query?

In the WHERE clause you appear to think you are querying from two tables:

```
WHERE b.state = school.state
```

but your FROM clause only specifies a single table:

```
FROM school b
```

The error messages is telling you that `school.state` is an invalid identifier.  This is in fact true, because you have aliased the SCHOOL table, so only `b.state` is valid in the scope of the statement.

I think you trying to identify the IDs of schools which are in the same state as other schools.  In which case you need to join it to itself, something like this:

```
SELECT TOP (20) b.id 
FROM school a join school b 
   on  b.state = a.state 
      and  b.id <> a.id
```

Comment: You are correct, I am trying to select 20 random schools that belong to the same state. And.. your query works ;) I had to change school.id to b.id though. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 2):

You are making the table "school" have the alias "b".  Once you do that, SQL will no longer recognize the column "school.state".  This begs the question, what is the "Where" condition you are trying to query against here?

Comment: I think there is a table "b". Add a comment between school and b if they are different tables you are selecting from.

Comment: @David That's not how SQL syntax works. If you specify a table in the FROM clause, and then immediately follow it with anything that is not a keyword, it becomes an alias for that table.

Comment: @TiesonT. I know, but the person asking the question may not know. With the SQL he provided, it seems like he is comparing two tables. He should provide his SQL table, and what he is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @David Then make your comment on the question, and on not dbaseman's answer, where it's out of context.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared table `school` and renamed original table to an alias `b`. You should join the table school with itself like this:

```
SELECT TOP (20) id FROM school b
INNER JOIN school s ON b.state = s.state 
WHERE b.id <> s.id 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```